# Right clicking start menu items brings up blue menu (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8.1, context-menu

When I right click on an item, this happens:

[image]

Other context menus are unchanged:

[image]

PC is running Windows 8.1 64-bit, AMD radeon graphics, Intel i7 processor. More detailed specs can be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with the update [KB3072318](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3072318). Uninstall it to fix the issue. Microsoft is aware of it and will fix it in a later update.